# Will there be a fix for having to swap Linkkeys for the bluetooth function?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, bluetooth

I am running Win10.1 & Kubuntu !8.04. I have been searching all around the internet and it seems a not so easy method to get a bluetooth device to reconnect after booting into the other OS, is to swap the link keys. I seem to remember a time where that was not necessary.

Will there be a ifx for this soon? I change between the two OS' quite often, and it really is a bother to have to re-pair/add device everytime I boot into the OS. I have a built-in Bluetooth adapter which I like using as it doesn't take up yet another USB port on my laptop...bluetooth, pairing,